# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError one route two components

Tags: components, angular2-routing

I have the /coaching route.

If I am a super-admin, I can see the list of all coach-admins from the system (guess right, when going on /coaching route (pressing a button)).
If I am a coach admin, I can see the list of all coaches from the system. (Again, I want to use the same /coaching route).

I have created 3 components in this case: CoachAdminListComponent, CoachListComponent and CoachComponent. The html of the CoachComponent looks like the following:

```
<app-coach-admin-list
  *ngIf="isCurrentUserSuperAdmin()"
  [items]="coachAdmins$ | async"
  [itemInfo]="coachAdminInfo$ | async"
  [loggedUser]="loggedUser"
  [cachedItems]="allCoachAdmins$ | async"
  [loading]="loading"
  (onSubmit)="handleOnSubmit($event)"
  (onFilter)="handleOnFilter($event)"
  (onMenuItem)="handleOnMenuItem($event)">
</app-coach-admin-list>
<app-coach-list
  *ngIf="!isCurrentUserSuperAdmin()"
  [items]="coaches$ | async"
  [itemInfo]="organisationInfo$ | async"
  [loggedUser]="loggedUser"
  [cachedItems]="allCoaches$ | async"
  [loading]="loading"
  (onSubmit)="handleOnSubmit($event)"
  (onFilter)="handleOnFilter($event)"
  (onMenuItem)="handleOnMenuItem($event)">
 </app-coach-list>
```

I understand that this is an ugly code, but how can I display each component when the role is convenient for them?

I got the following error when trying to log in as a coach admin:

```
 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression 
 has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. 
 Current value: 'false'.
```

The coach.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
 path: 'coaching',
 component: CoachComponent,
 canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}];
```

Of couse, the coach component has the 2 modules included in its file, so I am trying to find how to render this without having the error and also in a clear manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting up `isCurrentUserSuperAdmin` as a property and not a function,
set it in the `ngOnInit()`.

Your Component Class now look like

```
export class CoachComponent implements OnInit{ 
     isUserSuperAdmin:boolean;

     public ngOnInit(){
            this.isUserSuperAdmin = this.CheckIfSuperAdmin();
     }
     public CheckIfSuperAdmin(){
         //your logic to check if super admin
     }

}
```